# Reorder only a part of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

**Context**

I have a pandas-DataFrame with a structure analogous to something like the table on the left:

```
      + Category + Content + Layer                + Category + Content + Layer
Index |          |         |                Index |          |         |      
----------------------------------          ----------------------------------  
000001|   "A"    | "Dummy" |  0         ->  000001|   "A"    | "Dummy" |  0   
----------------------------------          ----------------------------------
000002|   "A"    | "Dummy" |  1         ->  000003|   "A"    | "Dummy" |  0   
----------------------------------          ----------------------------------
000003|   "A"    | "Dummy" |  0         ->  000002|   "A"    | "Dummy" |  1   
----------------------------------          ----------------------------------
000004|   "A"    | "Dummy" |  1         ->  000004|   "A"    | "Dummy" |  1    
----------------------------------          ----------------------------------
000005|   "B"    | "Dummy" |  2         =   000005|   "B"    | "Dummy" |  2   
----------------------------------          ----------------------------------
000006|   "B"    | "Dummy" |  0         =   000006|   "B"    | "Dummy" |  0   
----------------------------------          ----------------------------------
000007|   "B"    | "Dummy" |  4         =   000007|   "B"    | "Dummy" |  4   
----------------------------------          ----------------------------------
```

What I want to achieve is to reorder the dataframe like on the right.

**Question**

As shown in the right table, only a part of the dataframe is supposed to be reordered - Only elements of `category == "A"` shall be ordered in ascending manner of their `layer`.
All elements of `category == "B"`have to stay as they are (which is my current problem when working with `dataframe.sort_values()` etc.).

***How can I reorder (resort) only the specified part of the dataframe without affecting the rest?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in two steps:

1. Filter rows by condition, for example by creating a boolean `mask`
2. Directly address the underlying numpy-arrays via `.loc` (in order to prevent the alignment of index values)

> `.loc`: Access a group of rows and columns by label(s) or a boolean array.
>   ([Link to pandas-Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html))

```
    #Boolean mask of the entire dataframe in order to identify relevant rows
    mask = df['Category'].eq('A')     #Anlog to mask = (df["Category"] == 'A')

    #pandas >= 0.24
    df.loc[mask] = df.loc[mask].sort_values('Layer').to_numpy()

    #pandas < 0.24
    df.loc[mask] = df.loc[mmask.sort_values('Layer').values

    #Result
    print (df)
           Category Content  Layer
    Index                         
    000001        A   Dummy      0
    000002        A   Dummy      0
    000003        A   Dummy      1
    000004        A   Dummy      1
    000005        B   Dummy      2
    000006        B   Dummy      0
    000007        B   Dummy      4
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, works when I adapt it to my problem :)